# Python - track inputs

Tags: python-3.x

I am having difficulty keeping a track of the total number of inputs. I want my program to keep track of the total number of inputs and print it when my while loop breaks. Any help is appreciated!

```
r = float(input("enter r:"))

def main(r):
    a = 3.14 * (float(r ** 2))
    s_v = 0
    total = 0

    while True:
        r = float(input("enter r:"))

        if r == sentinal_value:
            total += r
            print("Total = " , total)
            break

        else:
            print("Area = ", a)

            continue

main(r)
```

Comment: shouldn't you just add 1 instead `r` to `total`?

Comment: You should have a variable that keeps track of the number of times it's looped, start it at 0, and then increment it every time you go through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want your program to re-calculate the area with each iteration. As written, it will only be calculated the first time you run the `mymian` function. You don't need to pass any arguments to the function.

```
def mymian():

    sentinal_value = 0
    total = 0

    while True:
        r = float(input("enter r:"))

        if r == sentinal_value:

            print("Total number of r provided to this program" , total)
            break

        else:
            print("Area = ", 3.14 * (float(r ** 2)))
            total += 1
            continue
```